# Destroy Clone On Click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy

I currently been trying for 2 days now to destroy an instantiated prefab clone with a mouse click.

The code below does 2 things auto destroys them after a set interval which works great. The click function destroys all the clones even if i click on the prefab or not which isn't what I'm wanting it to do.

**Update:** This project is in 2d

I'm have searched on here and have asked others on different scripting platforms and their advice doesn't seem to help.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class DestroyOnClick : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float lifeTime = 10f;


     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
         {
             Destruction();
         }

         if (lifeTime > 0)
         {
             lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
             if(lifeTime <= 0)
             {
                 Destruction();
             }
         }


     }


     void Destruction()
     {
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
     }
 }
```

Comment: // It only trigger on the attacked gameobject 

 `void OnMouseDown() {
     Destruction();
 }`

Comment: that doesn't help me.....could you provide me some code that would make it so when i click my spawned clone it destroys.only the one i'm clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Monobehaviour implement the PointerClick or PointerDown Event handler, and make sure you have an EventSystem in your scene, and a raycaster on the active camera.

```
//something along these lines:
using UnityEngine;
public class DestroyOnClick : Monobehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerClickEventData data)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one again, and still doesn't seem to work have physics 2d raycaster in the camera and canvas. I also, have this script on my prefab without the desroy function instead i added a debug.log message saying i click this object and when i run the game and click my cloned prefab nothing shows in console?

Comment: Well, after many many hours of messing around. it all came down too Graphic raycaster's not being in my canvas....

Answer (score 0):

because update will running all gameobject , dont use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` in update

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class DestroyOnClick : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float lifeTime = 10f;


     void Update()
     {
         if (lifeTime > 0)
         {
             lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
             if(lifeTime <= 0)
             {
                 Destruction();
             }
         }


     }
     //write here , it only work in this gameobject
     void OnMouseDown() { Destruction(); }

     void Destruction()
     {
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Okay, so managed to fix the previous error that i was getting. However, the clone doesn't get destroyed when i click it....nothing happens.

Comment: here is my spawn script which is attached to an empty game object named spawner and its located in my canvas....https://i.gyazo.com/701a6c0e9caf068dc45921ff5eaeab1c.png...anyways have to get some sleep will look at this thread tomorrow to see anymore solutions....thanks timchang for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution would be to put a collider on the clone you're trying to destroy and put a new script on your clone (or modify the script that you already have on your clone).

The Script would have to contain this method:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

or

```
private void OnMouseUp()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Both methods will destroy the clicked GameObject but they will be executed in different stages of the click. OnMouseDown() is called when you press the mouse button down and OnMouseUp is called when you

Comment: I tried the top code and put it into my current script and ran the project my clones started spawning in and tried to click one and it didn't nothing didn't get destroyed in the hierarchy....so not sure whats going on